# SharePoint 2010 versioning

Tags: sharepoint-server, versioning

We would like to implement SharePoint versioning but our QMS Controlled Documents already have version which is done manually. Is there a way to set up versioning and then set the version number to start so that subsequent versions increment correctly?

For example: I currently have document called *travel_document.08* (version 8). If I upload it to SharePoint, the new versioning will set this document to version 0 instead of 8 which is the actual document version. Ideally, we need to have this uploaded as version 8. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this.  It might be possible using some clever coding(?), but I wouldn't know where to start.  Using the normal, standard version control you would need to edit/approve until the file reached version 8.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use workflow action to update the document file name with the version number when the item is changed.

Open SharePoint Designer, create a workflow associated with the document library. In the workflow settings, tick "Start workflow automatically when the item is change". In the workflow step, add "Update List Item" action to edit the document name with relevant version.